# How add ActionListener to dynamically created JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I want to dynamically create a `JFrame` with a text field and two buttons. The problem is that `JTextField` is not visible inside the `ActionListener` of `JButton` (`treePanel.addObject(txt.getText());`). How to solve this issue?

```
JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
        addButton.setActionCommand(ADD_COMMAND);
        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
            {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Add new group/subgroup");
                JPanel p = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
                p.add(new JLabel("Group/subgroup name: "));
                JTextField txt = new JTextField(10);
                JButton ok = new JButton("Ok");
                JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
                p.add(txt,"wrap");
                p.add(ok); 
                p.add(cancel);
                f.add(p);

                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);                    
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
                ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                    {
                        treePanel.addObject(txt.getText()); 
                    }
                });
                cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                    {
                        f.dispose();    
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: set `txt` as `final` or instance variable. Also read about [variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html).

Answer (score 3):

Anonymous classes is an **inner classes** and the strict rule applies to **inner classes** [`(JLS 8.1.3)`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.1.3):

> Any local variable, formal method parameter or exception handler parameter used but not declared in an inner class **must be declared final**. 
>   Any local variable, used but not declared in an inner class **must be definitely assigned before the body of the inner class**.

So in your case you need to change the `txt` to be a final regarding the above rule.

```
final JTextField txt = new JTextField(10);
```